# Characteristic property of field $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Given that $K$ is a field, $\text{char}(K)=p$ (where $p$ is prime) we need to show that for any integer $n$ the equality

$$
(a+b)^{p^n} =a^{p^n}+b^{p^n}
$$
We have the following

$$n=0:\qquad(a+b)^{p^0}=a+b=a^{p^0}+b^{p^0}$$
$$\text{Induction hypothesis}:\qquad (a+b)^{p^n}=a^{p^n}+b^{p^n}$$
$$n+1 \text{ case}:\qquad (a+b)^{p^{n+1}}=((a+b)^{p^{n}})^p=(a^{p^n}+b^{p^n})^p$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^{p} \binom{p}{k}(a^{p^n})^{p-k}(b^{p^n})^{k}$$
$$=a^{p+1}+b^{p+1}+\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{k}(a^{p^n})^{p-k}(b^{p^n})^{k}$$

In order to complete the proof we need to get $\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{k}(a^{p^n})^{p-k}(b^{p^n})^{k}=0$ and we know that we need to use the characteristic property of $K$ somehow, however we don't know in what way.

Comment: It's easier to show that $(x+y)^p=x^p+y^p$ then set $x=a^{p^n}$, $y=b^{p^n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write 
$\displaystyle \binom{p}{k} 
=  \frac{p\times(p-1)\times\cdots\times(p-k+1)}{1\times 2\times\cdots\times k}$, recall that $\displaystyle \binom{p}{k}$ is an *integer*,
and argue that *none* of those multiplicands in the denominator
can cancel out that $p$ in the numerator: they must be cancelling
out with the $(p-1)\times\cdots\times(p-k+1)$ part to leave you with an
integer that is obviously a multiple of $p$.

Comment: this answer makes sense if you calculate modulo $p$. How can we see that this is the case?

Comment: Well, since everything is in a field of characteristic $p$, why would you not be doing the arithmetic modulo $p$? More straightforwardly, $\binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}$ is _shorthand_ for the sum $$\underbrace{x^ky^{n-k}+x^ky^{n-k}+\cdots+x^ky^{n-k}}_{\binom{n}{k}~\text{terms}}$$ where $\binom{n}{k}$ is calculated in $\mathbb R$ and not the finite field, but the net effect is that since the number of identical terms being added together (in the finite field) is a multiple of $p$, the sum is $0$.